# MongoDb: ConnectionFailure: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, django, mongodb

when I am trying to

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

The following error occure

```
ConnectionFailure: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I am switch my sqlite database to mongodb

I am tring on python manage.py shell

```
In [1]: from pymongo import MongoClient

In [2]: client = MongoClient()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionFailure                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/nik4u/Projects/ABEC-Dev-Env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 client = MongoClient()

/home/nik4u/Projects/ABEC-Dev-Env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.pyc in __init__(self, host, port, max_pool_size, document_class, tz_aware, _connect, **kwargs)
    375             except AutoReconnect, e:
    376                 # ConnectionFailure makes more sense here than AutoReconnect
--> 377                 raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
    378 
    379         if username:

ConnectionFailure: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: is `mongod` up and running?

Comment: I don't think so. check again

Comment: `mongodb start/running, process 9201
`

Comment: this only means that upstart tried starting mongodb, it doesn't mean that it started successfully. does `pgrep mongod` output anything?

Comment: yeah Its give output `9201`

Comment: There could be a firewall that prevent connection. Are you able to connect to mongod from console?

Answer (score 0):

You need not perform `python manage.py syncdb` with `mongodb`

In your settings, make the following changes.

```
MONGO_SETTINGS = {
    'default' : {
        'DB_NAME'  : 'db_name',
        'HOST': 'mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/db_name',
        'PORT'     : 27017,
        'MAX_POOL_SIZE' : 100,
    }}
```

,

```
for conn, attrs in MONGO_SETTINGS.items():

    mongoengine.connect(attrs['DB_NAME'], conn,
    host=attrs['HOST'], port=attrs['PORT'],
    username=attrs['USERNAME'], password=attrs['PASSWORD'],
    max_pool_size=attrs['MAX_POOL_SIZE'])
```

Django is not meant to handle non-relational databases. Forget all about migrations and syncdb.